# Hyperledger Fabric, How to apply Endorsement Logic

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

[Hyperledger Fabric Readthedocs__Endorsing Node](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/arch-deep-dive.html#the-endorsing-peer-simulates-a-transaction-and-produces-an-endorsement-signature)

In the above link, Endorsing Peer executes Transaction and signs tran-proposal according to endorsing logic. However, there is no description of Endorsing Logic anywhere else in this document.

What I want to do is verify the contents of a transaction. So I want to use Endorsing Logic, can you tell me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact the endorsing logic is in a sense is the literally business logic of your chaincode.

Once chaincode code executed and there is no error in results, peer uses ESCC (Endorsement System Chaincode) to actually sign these results, such that later on peer will be using signatures of endorsers for same transaction proposal to validate the conformance with [Endorsement Policy](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/endorsement-policies.html). Which basically takes care to validate whenever executions results are consistent and deterministic, for example you can have your endorsement policy:

```
AND(Org1.member, Org2.member)
```

meaning that execution of same chaincode for same input on peers of `Org1` and `Org2` are the same, prior to commit peer leverages VSCC(Validation System Chaincode) to actually enforce endorsement policy.

Now, you can also do your own ESCC and VSCC to hold your custom logic if you'd like to add something else.

Comment: In your example, despite Org1.member and Org2.member have the same chaincode, can they create different results?

Comment: if for example chaincode computes local time and tries to save it to the state, while clocks are not in sync, this will produce different result no matter the fact it's exactly same chaincode executed on both. you need to take care and keep in mind that given same state and same input parameters chaincode has to provide consistently same results.